# Docstring not showing up when importing .py file as a module?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, module, docstring

I am working on a project and I am beginning to write functions in other .py files and importing them to the main .py... I want to write help text for the entire file ( module ) that I am importing, similar to when importing a library ( module ) like this:[image: Hovering over tempfile module in vs code]

When I try writing something similar at the top of the file I'm importing, the docstring doesn't show up.

Trying this:
[image: Attempting to write a docstring in the file I'm importing]

But getting this (with no docstring showing):
[image: Hovering over the .py file I'm trying to import]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of your docstring format probably. Try to use such formatting:

```py
"""Helpful docstring for a .py file of functions."""
```

Then, if VS Code still doesn't show a docstring when a module hovering, use *Reload Window* command after saving your file (i. e. `Ctrl+Shift+P` and enter 'reload window'). You can use *pydocstyle* linter also. It says, for example, that "One-line docstring should fit on one line with quotes". The linter is supported by *Python* VS Code extension. But be sure, that `python.linting.pydocstyleEnabled` option is enabled and *pydocstyle* is installed itself. You can install it globally or locally for your virtual environment. I prefer the global installation - `pip install pydocstyle`. Also the extension checks, whether all enabled linters are installed and can help to install them.

Comment: I really really doubt it’s the formatting by type of quotes or the linefeed.  Docstrings need to be on first non-blank line of scope, is all.  Could be reload was needed or vscode fussiness, but Python generally considers single and double quotes equivalent even if there are stylistic preferences in, for example, linters and **black**.

Answer (score 1):

## Re: Solved

As suggested in the comments both ' ' and " " are equivalent. The problem had to do with reloading the window as suggested with `Ctrl+Shift+P` and 'reload window'.
[image: Docstring Working]
The docstring from importing a file must not directly update when changed

Answer (score 0):

I hit another case.

If you add `help="text"` inside of `command()` then y

That is,

```
@click.command(help="My cool utility")
@click.argument("fizz", required=True)
@click.argument("buzz", required=True)
def utility(fizz: str, buzz: str):
    """This utility is amazing"""
```

Then your doc string is **not** going to show up when you do `--help`.

Remove `help="My cool utility"` and you are good.